# MySQL ERROR: Column 'Time' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL ERROR: Column 'Time' cannot be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123786/mysql-error-column-time-cannot-be-null)

I am getting the error: Column 'Time' cannot be null, this is my code:

```
$table = "highscores";

// Initialization
$conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $conn);

// Error checking
if(!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect ' . mysql_error());
}

if($_GET['secret'] != "5920239") {
            header("Location: /404.html");
    exit();
}

// Localize the GET variables
$user   = isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : "";
$time   = isset($_GET['time']) ? $_GET['time']  : "";
$videos  = isset($_GET['videos']) ? $_GET['videos'] : "";
$credits  = isset($_GET['credits']) ? $_GET['credits'] : "";

// Protect against sql injections
$user  = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
$time  = mysql_real_escape_string($time);
$videos = mysql_real_escape_string($videos);
$credits = mysql_real_escape_string($credits);
$secret = mysql_real_escape_string($secret);

// Insert/UPDATE
$retval = mysql_query("
     INSERT INTO
     $table(Username, Time, Videos, Credits)
     VALUES
     ('$user', '$time', '$videos', '$credits')
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
     Time = DATE_ADD(IFNULL(Time,now()),INTERVAL '$time' SECOND),
     Videos = Videos+'$videos',
     Credits = Credits+'$credits'
     ",
     $conn
     );
    // End Query


if($retval) {
    echo "Success! Updated $user with Time: $time - Videos: $videos - Credits: $credits";
} else {
    echo "<b>ERROR:</b><br>" . mysql_error();
}

mysql_close($conn);
```

I only get the error when 'Username' is a duplicate, otherwise it will insert fine.

If you need any more information/need me to do anything then please post and I will respond asap, thanks in advance to everyone who helps!

Comment: What is the type of `Time` column? Full column definition in your `CREATE TABLE` statement can be helpful.

Comment: The problem lies with `Time = DATE_ADD(IFNULL(Time,now()),INTERVAL '$time' SECOND)`--somehow it's setting Time to NULL.  Perhaps because $time is undefined?  Since I don't know what your input looks like, I can't be sure of the exact cause, but this is where you need to be investigating.

Comment: Try using `$time = int($time);` instead of `$time  = mysql_real_escape_string($time);` and replace `INTERVAL '$time' SECOND` with `INTERVAL $time SECOND`.  On a separate note, you will be less likely to let a security issue slip through if you use prepared queries with placeholders, rather than manually escaping each variable.

Comment: @nobody the type of the `Time` column is Time @Conspicuous Compiler Just tried that and I still get the same error,`Column 'Time' cannot be null `

Comment: @gbn This question actually comes from that answer. The OP should have just edited the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DATE_ADD()` can't work on `TIME` data type, the first argument can only be a `DATE`. Also assigning `'100'` to a `TIME` column results in `'00:01:00'` which I don't think is what you want. I believe for what you want to do you should be using a column with `TIMESTAMP` type or just `UNSIGNED INT` and replace your DATE_ADD() with a simple + operation.

Comment: it now updates using seconds with an INT, is there a way I can convert this is HH:MM:SS when displaying it in a leaderboards (php)?

Comment: You can use `SEC_TO_TIME( seconds )` in MySql to convert seconds to HH:MM:SS format.

Comment: Okay will use that, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting a value to `$time`? You have code to initialize it to `""` if `$_GET['time']` is not passed, and that could be causing your issue.

Comment: Yes I am setting a value for it in the URL it is being set, send.php?time=100 etc.

Comment: Try implementing @Conspicuous Compiler's suggestion in your question

Comment: just added that in and I still get the error `Column 'Time' cannot be null`

Comment: Keep updating your question with things that you have tried so that we all are aware of the current status